# How to get the first embed content of a post

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, embed, vimeo

I'm trying to get the first embed url from the post. 
I know wordpress auto-embeds them but can't find a method to just get the
embeds.

```
                 $urls = array();
                 $p = get_post();
                 preg_match('@https?://(www.)?(youtube|vimeo)\.com/(watch\?v=)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@im', $p->post_content, $urls);
                 echo wp_oembed_get( $urls[0] );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Wordpress 2.9, wp_oembed_get function has been included.

Example:

```
<?php $embed_code = wp_oembed_get($url); ?>
```

Here is the link to the function, to get the embeds:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the first `[embed]` shortcode:

```
function sofa_get_embed_shortcode($content) {
    preg_match('/\[embed(.*)](.*)\[\/embed]/', $content, $matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

Pass `$post->post_content` as the `$content` variable, and you'll receive an array of the `[embed]` shortcodes found.

Comment: Does WP replace the http://youtube... with an embed tag? I want the user to just paste the URL.